# Open Pdf in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

On Button Click I generate a PDF file and then open it at client side with:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(path);
```

This will show the pdf in the browser, but in the same tab. How can I open it in a new tab?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/4-ways-to-send-a-PDF-file-to-the-IE-Client-in-ASPNET-20.aspx) blog post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script  language=vbscript>
sub OpenInNewWindow()
    window.open("PDFContainer.aspx")
end sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Way 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type=button OnClick="OpenInNewWindow()"  value="Open in New Window"/>
        <br /><br />
        This time, we will open a new Internet Explorer Window and Show the PDF File directly in the IE
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 just for the rare experience of seeing client-side VBScript

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the server side. It is a client side operation. see [Create a new tab or window for a web page from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488311/create-a-new-tab-or-window-for-a-web-page-from-asp-net)